# Read a .doc file line by line in python using win32com

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to extract the title and some other data from reports with .doc (NOT .docx!) format. The code I have written so far, reads the whole text alltogether ignoring lines and paragraphs (either directly reading or saving into a .txt file):

```
DOC_FILEPATH = os.path.join('file.doc')
doc = win32com.client.GetObject(DOC_FILEPATH)
text= doc.Range().Text
```

How can I read the file so that it preserves the lines and paragraphs as they are?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my problem. Probably useful for similar cases. The tag `.Text` should be removed from the end of `text= doc.Range().Text`, then the reader preseves the lines and paragraphs nicely :). So the correct code whould be something like:

```
DOC_FILEPATH = os.path.join('file.doc')
doc = win32com.client.GetObject(DOC_FILEPATH)
text= doc.Range()
```